# How to rotate 3d model when a key press happens in threejs and start animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3d

I am working on a project in which person *(gltf object)* is walking based on key press. I am able to update the object position based on key press.

But I am unable to rotate the object when *left/right* key is pressed and continue walking in that direction

Attaching the code for reference.

```js
import { OrbitControls } from '../assets/js/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from '../assets/js/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OBJLoader } from '../assets/js/OBJLoader.js';

var camera, scene, renderer, clock, man_walk, gltfLoader, mixer, action, objLoader, keyboard;

init();
animate();

function init(){

    // Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.gammaOutput = true
    clock = new THREE.Clock();
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xC3D8D6 );
    // scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 0, 750 );

    // Camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.y = 250;
    camera.position.z = 600;

    // Light
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040);
    scene.add(light);

    //keyevents
    keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
    // console.log(keyboard);
    // // Controls
    // var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    // controls.enableDampling = true;
    // controls.campingFactor = 0.25;
    // controls.enableZoom = true;
    // var vector = camera.getWorldDirection();
    // console.log(vector);

    getAlternateTiles();
    getFloorMaterialByImage();

    gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    objLoader = new OBJLoader();
    loadDoor();
    loadMan();
}

function loadDoor(){

    objLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/Doorway/Doorway.obj', object => {
        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child.type == "Mesh") {
              child.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            }
        });
        
        scene.add(object);
        object.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 2;
        object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    
        object.scale.multiplyScalar(30);
        object.position.z = 100
    });

}

function loadMan(){
    
    gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/boy_animated/scene.gltf', gltf => {
        man_walk = gltf.scene;
        man_walk.position.set(0, 0, 60);
        man_walk.rotateY(210.5);
        scene.add(man_walk);
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(man_walk);
        mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();
    });
}

function getAlternateTiles() {
    var segments = 50;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 5000, segments, segments);
    geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
    var materialEven = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x85A95D});
    var materialOdd = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x93BC54});
    
    // #485C64
    var materials = [materialEven, materialOdd];
    
    for(var x=0; x<segments; x++) {
        for(var y=0; y<segments; y++) {
            var i = x * segments + y;
            var j = 2 * i;
            geometry.faces[ j ].materialIndex = geometry.faces[ j + 1 ].materialIndex = (x + y) % 2;
        }
    }
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
    scene.add(mesh);
}

function getFloorMaterialByImage() {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000, 10, 10 );
    geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
    // lightwood.jpg, whitetiles.jpg, floorline.jpg, woodsheet.jpg, Carpet.jpeg, Wood_Bamboo.jpeg, corporate.jpg
    var floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '/assets/img/floorline.jpg' );
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorTexture.repeat.set(20, 20);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: floorTexture});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
}

// Animate
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    updateMan();
}


function updateMan(){

var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; 

var moveDistance = 150 * delta; // 100 pixels per second
var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second

if ( keyboard.pressed("a") ){
    man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
}
if ( keyboard.pressed("d") ){
    man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
} 
if ( keyboard.pressed("w") ){
    man_walk.translateZ(- moveDistance);
    mixer.update(delta);
}
var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,250,600);
var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( man_walk.matrixWorld );
camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
camera.lookAt(man_walk.position);
}

function render() 
{
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Animation using for project:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/nathan-animated-003-walking-3d-man-143a2b1ea5eb4385ae90a73657aca3bc

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Your code does show the keyboard left/right checks, but I don't see any code to perform the rotation in these checks. What coffee did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: When I try to add `man_walk.rotate()` in the if else ladder, it is rotating continously

Comment: What happens when you place the `render()` call after `updateMan()`? And you probably mean `man_walk.rotateY(angle)` instead of plain `.rotate()`?

Comment: yes, I want the man to rotate z when i click  `a` and start walking in that direction

Comment: @MaartenVeerman like we see in FPS games

Comment: updated my code, but I want the person to face in oppisite direction

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `updateMan()` function to look camera at the person model always. And the relativeCameraOffset should be in oppsite direction of the actual camera position.

Please see the code attached.

Correct me if something is wrong.

```js
function updateMan(){

    var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
    var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; 

 var moveDistance = 150 * delta; // 100 pixels per second
    var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second
    
    if ( keyboard.pressed("a") ){
        man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
    }
 if ( keyboard.pressed("d") ){
        man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
    } 
 if ( keyboard.pressed("w") ){
        man_walk.translateZ(moveDistance);
        mixer.update(delta);
    }
    var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,250,-600);
 var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( man_walk.matrixWorld );
    camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
    camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
    camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
    camera.lookAt(man_walk.position);
}
```